# no matching function for a call to naiveGaussianElimination

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array

I am trying to debugg this, but can't figure out the issue here. Why is it saying no matching function for a call to naiveGaussianElimination evnthough i have passed the correct parameters?

```
void naiveGaussianElimination(int count,float doubleCoefficient[][count+1]) {


}


int main() {
    /*
     Read from file and assign values to vector
     */

    //File stream object
    ifstream inputFile;

    // store file name
    string fileName;

    // ask user for the file name and store it
    cout << "Enter the file name:>> ";
    cin >> fileName;

    //Open the txt file
    inputFile.open(fileName.c_str());

    //search for the text file
    if(!inputFile.is_open())
    {
        cerr << "Error opening file \n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File found and successfully opened. \n";
    }

    /*
     find the number of variables in the equation
     */
    int count =0;
    string line;
    while (getline(inputFile, line)){

        count++;
    }

    cout << "Number of variables: " << count << endl;   // show total variables in text file

    // clear the eof flag and set it to top
    inputFile.clear();
    inputFile.seekg (0, ios::beg);


    // 2D array to store augmented matrix
    float doubleCoefficient [count][count+1];

    naiveGaussianElimination(count,doubleCoefficient);
    inputFile.close();
}
```

Comment: What do you have an operator in your function declaration?
`void naiveGaussianElimination(int count,float doubleCoefficient[][count+1])`

Comment: @ 40Alpha:: which one? count+1 ??

Comment: Yup, just add `1` to the parameter within your function.

Comment: it doesn't make a difference, does it? I need to have my columns 1 greater than the row!

Comment: add 1 to the parameter? I don't get it.

Comment: @user3504305: It makes a huge difference. You can't name types that way.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

**Use dynamic array for

//2D dynamic array to store augmented matrix**

```
float **doubleCoefficient = new float*[count];
    for (int i=0; i<(count+1); i++) {
        doubleCoefficient[i] = new float[count+1];
    }
}
```

Comment: No, do not do this. Yuck. Yikes. Eugh! This is a terrible idea. You want a `std::vector<float>` wrapped by a type that performs 2D<->1D index translation for you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Why yikes? Its good rather than making a complicated vector.

Comment: Vectors are not "complicated". Indirection with dynamically-allocated arrays is "complicated". The number of ways you can go wrong with this in hard-to-diagnose ways is remarkable, not to mention you have an entire order of magnitude more dynamic allocations than are necessary.